# Can I have a price set option add a registrant to the waitlist if the event isn't full?

Tags: civievent, registration, price-sets, waitlist

I have what may be a tricky situation regarding registration and waitlists.

We have an event where we have two potential types of registrants: residents of a jurisdiction and people who live outside of the jurisdiction. People pick if there's a resident or non-resident in price options when they go through event registration.

Those who pick the Resident price option should go through registration and fee payment normally and end up with a "registered" status when they're done.

We want people who pick the Non-Resident price option to not pay anything and be set to a waitlist status once they're done with registration. We would then manually move them to "registered" if there's enough room after a certain date.

Question 1: Is this a normal part of CiviEvent functionality that I'm just not able to find?

Question 2: We had a developer set up a price set like this that does work. We copied it, changed label names, and tried to use the new price set for another event, and the non-registrants are ending up "registered" instead of "waitlist." Any advice on how to successfully replicate that original price set? I just recently got access to cPanel for our site and I'm not sure what to look for here.

I appreciate any advice you may have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like maybe your coder wrote an extension that relies on price set labels rather than names?  Check **Administer >> System Settings >> Extensions** for a likely-looking extension.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to ask the resident/non-resident question first and direct them to two separate events: a residents one for immediate registration and a non-residents one with a max participants of 0.

When you want to allow non-residents to book you have two basic options:

1. open up non-resident bookings by changing the max participants on the non-resident event
2. find a way to transfer waitlist registrations from the non-resident event to the resident event.

For 1), you end up with registrations spread across two events which is not ideal but may or may not matter to you.  To manage further registrations you probably want to close the residents event at the same time and direct any new registrations to the non-res one so that you can still manage total numbers.

For 2), I don't think there is an easy way to transfer registrations between events without some coding.

You mention cPanel - that's not relevant here.  Event configuration is under the Event menu:
[image]

Comment: With a Drupal VBO it may be possible to alter which Event a Participant is registered for. We took a look at this a while ago and it seemed feasible (think we had CiviCRM Entity module in place too)